# Dictionary of Objects/Classes in VBScript

Tags: object, dictionary, vbscript

Is it possible to have a dictionary of object/classes in vbscript?

For example:

```
Class employeeclass
    Public first, last, salary
End Class
Dim employeedict: Set employeedict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Loop would be here
Dim employee: Set employee = new employeeclass
With employee
    .first = "John"
    .last = "Doe"
    .salary = 50000
End With
employeedict.Add "1", employee
```

EDIT **The above does work**.

Comment: In general, "does not work" is not a decent decription of a failure. In this case it is a blatant lie, the code as given stores the 'Doe' object in the dictionary under key "1".

Comment: It didn't compile before...but it does now...not enough coffee before=P. So apparently it does work (my mistake). I've posted a "community wiki" answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answering own question)

Yes, its possible to use a dictionary of objects/classes in VBScript. The following is an example for those interested:

```
Class employeeclass
    Public first, last, salary
End Class
Dim employeedict: Set employeedict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim employee: Set employee = new employeeclass
With employee
    .first = "John"
    .last = "Doe"
    .salary = 50000
End With
employeedict.Add "1", employee

Set employee = new employeeclass
With employee
    .first = "Mary"
    .last = "Jane"
    .salary = 50000
End With
employeedict.Add "3", employee

Dim employeedetails: Set employeedetails = employeedict.Item("1")
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Name:" & employeedetails.first & " " & employeedetails.last & " $" & employeedetails.salary )
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(employeedict.Item("3").first & " " & employeedict.Item("3").last & " makes $" & employeedict.Item("3").salary)
```

Prints out:

```
Name:John Doe $50000 
Mary Jane makes $50000
```