# Why is not a private variable accessible to all methods in a class of my VBScript code?

Tags: oop, vbscript

I hope someone can help me with my problem with Diadem and VBScript

In the `Class TelltaleCycle` the private variable `p_FunctionType` is modified for the first time in `Public Property Let TimestampCh(value2let)` and then it is accessed in `Public Property Get HowManyPeriods`. Although this variable should hold the value written in the `Public Property Let TimestampCh(value2let)` it is read as empty in `Public Property Get HowManyPeriods`. I can not figure out why of this behavior!
In the `Class BeltminderCycle` Im doing almost the same thing and it is working as expected.

PS: becareful while reading my code because the variable name `p_FunctionType` is used in other class as well.

Seatbelt_Library.vbs:

```
Option Explicit  'Forces the explicit declaration of all the variables in a script.

Dim oUDI : Set oUDI = CreateUDI

Class BeltminderCycle

    Private  p_Index
    Private  p_FunctionType
    Private  p_OrderOfThisType
    Private  p_StartTime
    Private  p_EndTime
    Private  p_Duration
    Private p_TelltaleObjIndex
    Private p_ChimeObjIndex

    Dim timestamp_channel_number, amplitude_channel_number

   Private Sub Class_Initialize
        p_Index = 0
        p_FunctionType = ""
        p_OrderOfThisType = 0
        p_StartTime = 0
        p_EndTime = 0
        p_Duration = 0
        p_ChimeObjIndex = 0
        p_TelltaleObjIndex = 0
   End Sub

    Public Property Get Index
    Index = p_Index
    End Property
   Public Property Let Index(value2let)
      p_Index = value2let
   End Property

    Public Property Get FunctionType
        FunctionType = p_FunctionType
    End Property
    Public Property Let FunctionType(value2let)
        p_FunctionType = value2let
    End Property


    Public Property Get OrderOfThisType
        OrderOfThisType = p_OrderOfThisType
    End Property
    Public Property Let OrderOfThisType(value2let)
        p_OrderOfThisType = value2let
    End Property    

    Public Property Get StartTime
        StartTime = p_StartTime
    End Property
    Public Property Let StartTime(value2let)
        p_StartTime = value2let
    End Property

    Public Property Get EndTime
        EndTime = p_EndTime
    End Property
    Public Property Let EndTime(value2let)
        p_EndTime = value2let
    End Property

    Public Property Get Duration
        Duration = p_EndTime - p_StartTime
    End Property

    Public Property Get TelltaleObjIndex
        TelltaleObjIndex = p_TelltaleObjIndex
    End Property
    Public Property Let TelltaleObjIndex(value2let)
        p_TelltaleObjIndex = value2let
    End Property

        Public Property Get ChimeObjIndex
        ChimeObjIndex = p_ChimeObjIndex
    End Property
    Public Property Let ChimeObjIndex(value2let)
        p_ChimeObjIndex = value2let
    End Property


    Public Sub  Reinitialize
        p_Index = null
        p_TimestampCh = null
        p_AmplitudeCh = null
        p_FunctionType = null
        p_OrderOfThisType = null
        p_StartTime = null
        p_EndTime = null
        p_Duration = null
        p_ChimeObjIndex = null
        p_TelltaleObjIndex = null
        End Sub

End Class

Class TelltaleCycle

    Private  p_Index
    Private  p_TimestampCh
    Private  p_AmplitudeCh
    Private  p_FunctionType
    Private  p_OrderOfThisType
    Private  p_StartTime
    Private  p_EndTime
    Private  p_Duration
    Private p_HowManyPeriods
    Dim     Size

    Dim timestamp_channel_number, amplitude_channel_number, PeriodBeginningsTime, PeriodBeginningsAmplitude

  Private Sub Class_Initialize
        p_Index = 0
        p_TimestampCh = ""
        p_AmplitudeCh = ""
        p_FunctionType = ""
        p_OrderOfThisType = 0
        p_StartTime = 0
        p_EndTime = 0
        p_Duration = 0
        p_HowManyPeriods = 0
   End Sub

    Public Property Get Index
    Index = p_Index
    End Property

  Public Property Let Index(value2let)
      p_Index = value2let
   End Property

    Public Property Get TimestampCh
    TimestampCh = p_TimestampCh
    End Property

    Public Property Let TimestampCh(value2let)
        Dim oMyChn, aString
        p_TimestampCh  = value2let
        Set oMyChn = Data.GetChannel(value2let)
        p_TimestampCh = oMyChn.Name 
        aString = Split(oMyChn.Name, "_", -1, 1)
        p_FunctionType = aString(2) & "_" & aString(3)
        p_OrderOfThisType = aString(4)
        p_StartTime = CHDx(1,CNo(value2let))
        p_EndTime = CHDx(ChnLength(value2let),CNo(value2let))
        p_Duration = p_EndTime - p_StartTime        
    End Property

    Public Property Get AmplitudeCh
    AmplitudeCh = p_AmplitudeCh   
    End Property

    Public Property Let AmplitudeCh(value2let)
        Dim oMyChn
        p_AmplitudeCh  = value2let
        Set oMyChn = Data.GetChannel(value2let)
        p_AmplitudeCh = oMyChn.Name
    End Property

    Public Property Get FunctionType
        FunctionType = p_FunctionType
    End Property

    Public Property Get OrderOfThisType
        OrderOfThisType = p_OrderOfThisType
    End Property

    Public Property Get StartTime
        StartTime = p_StartTime
    End Property

    Public Property Get EndTime
        EndTime = p_EndTime
    End Property

    Public Property Get Duration
        Duration = p_Duration
    End Property

    Public Property Get HowManyPeriods

        Dim iLoop, TimeChnLength,PBT,PBA


        Call LogFileWrite("p_FunctionType: " & p_FunctionType)


    If ((p_FunctionType <> "NotFlashing_NA")) Then
      Call ChnDifferentiate("ProcessedChannels/Telltale_Timestamp_" & p_FunctionType & "_" & p_OrderOfThisType,"ProcessedChannels/Telltale_Amplitude_" & p_FunctionType & "_" & p_OrderOfThisType,"ProcessedChannels/DifferentiatedX","ProcessedChannels/DifferentiatedY")
      Call ChnPeakFind("ProcessedChannels/DifferentiatedX","ProcessedChannels/DifferentiatedY","ProcessedChannels/PeakX","ProcessedChannels/PeakY",10000,"Max.Peaks","Amplitude")  
      TimeChnLength = ChnLength(CNo("ProcessedChannels/PeakX"))

       Dim temp 
        reDim PBT(TimeChnLength), PBA(TimeChnLength)
        For iLoop = 1 to TimeChnLength
        PBT(iLoop - 1) = CHDx(iLoop,CNo("ProcessedChannels/PeakX"))
        PBA(iLoop - 1) = PNo(p_TimestampCh,PBT(iLoop - 1))
        temp = PBA(iLoop - 1)
        PBA(iLoop - 1) = CHDx(PBA(iLoop - 1),CNo(p_AmplitudeCh))
      Next

      PeriodBeginningsTime = PBT
      PeriodBeginningsAmplitude = PBA
        HowManyPeriods = Ubound(PeriodBeginningsTime)

      Call ChnDel("ProcessedChannels/DifferentiatedX")
      Call ChnDel("ProcessedChannels/DifferentiatedY")
      Call ChnDel("ProcessedChannels/PeakX")
      Call ChnDel("ProcessedChannels/PeakY")
    End If
    End Property

    Public Sub  Reinitialize
        p_Index = 0
        p_TimestampCh = ""
        p_AmplitudeCh = ""
        p_FunctionType = ""
        p_OrderOfThisType = 0
        p_StartTime = 0
        p_EndTime = 0
        p_Duration = 0
        p_HowManyPeriods = 0
   End Sub

End Class

Class ChimeCycle

    Private  p_Index
    Private  p_TimestampCh
    Private  p_AmplitudeCh
    Private  p_FunctionType
    Private  p_OrderOfThisType
    Private  p_StartTime
    Private  p_EndTime
    Private  p_Duration
    Private p_HowManyPeriods

    Dim timestamp_channel_number, amplitude_channel_number, Periods

   Private Sub Class_Initialize
        p_Index = 0
        p_TimestampCh = ""
        p_AmplitudeCh = ""
        p_FunctionType = ""
        p_OrderOfThisType = 0
        p_StartTime = 0
        p_EndTime = 0
        p_Duration = 0
        p_HowManyPeriods = 0
   End Sub

    Public Property Get Index
    Index = p_Index
    End Property
   Public Property Let Index(value2let)
      p_Index = value2let
   End Property

    Public Property Get TimestampCh
    TimestampCh = p_TimestampCh
    End Property
    Public Property Let TimestampCh(value2let)
        Dim oMyChn, aString, iLoop
        p_TimestampCh  = value2let
        Set oMyChn = Data.GetChannel(value2let)
        p_TimestampCh = oMyChn.Name 
        aString = Split(oMyChn.Name, "_", -1, 1)
        p_FunctionType = aString(2) & "_" & aString(3)
        p_OrderOfThisType = aString(4)
        p_StartTime = CHDx(1,CNO(value2let))
        p_EndTime = CHDx(ChnLength(value2let),CNo(value2let))
        p_Duration = p_EndTime - p_StartTime + 0.030
        Periods = p_Duration/1
    End Property

    Public Property Get AmplitudeCh
    AmplitudeCh = p_AmplitudeCh
    End Property
    Public Property Let AmplitudeCh(value2let)
        Dim oMyChn
        p_AmplitudeCh  = value2let
        Set oMyChn = Data.GetChannel(value2let)
        p_AmplitudeCh = oMyChn.Name
    End Property

    Public Property Get FunctionType
        FunctionType = p_FunctionType
    End Property

    Public Property Get OrderOfThisType
        OrderOfThisType = p_OrderOfThisType
    End Property

    Public Property Get StartTime
        StartTime = p_StartTime
    End Property

    Public Property Get EndTime
        EndTime = p_EndTime
    End Property

    Public Property Get Duration
        Duration = p_Duration
    End Property    

    Public Property Get HowManyPeriods
        HowManyPeriods = Periods
    End Property    

    Public Sub  Reinitialize
        p_Index = 0
        p_TimestampCh = ""
        p_AmplitudeCh = ""
        p_FunctionType = ""
        p_OrderOfThisType = 0
        p_StartTime = 0
        p_EndTime = 0
        p_Duration = 0
        p_HowManyPeriods = 0
   End Sub

End Class

Function GenerateTimestampChn(TimestampChnName,AmplitudeChn,Fs,NewGrp)
    Dim ChannelLength, ret, iLoop

    ChannelLength = ChnLength(AmplitudeChn)
    ret = ChnAlloc(TimestampChnName, ChannelLength, 1, DataTypeFloat64,"Numeric",NewGrp)

    For iLoop = 1 to ChannelLength
        CHD(iLoop,CNo(ret(0))) = iLoop/Fs
    Next

    GenerateTimestampChn = ret(0)

End Function

Function ProcessNoise(AmplitudeChn,TimestampChn,Threshold,NewGrp)
    Dim iLoop, NewChn, L_TimestampChn, L_AmplitudeChn, L_Threshold
    L_TimestampChn  = TimestampChn
    L_AmplitudeChn = AmplitudeChn
    L_Threshold = Threshold

    NewChn=ChnAlloc(ChnName(L_AmplitudeChn) & "_Processed", ChnLength(L_AmplitudeChn), 1, ChnValueDataType(L_AmplitudeChn),"Numeric",NewGrp)
    L_AmplitudeChn = ChnCopy(L_AmplitudeChn,NewChn(0))
    NewChn=ChnAlloc(ChnName(L_TimestampChn) & "_Processed", ChnLength(L_TimestampChn), 1, ChnValueDataType(L_TimestampChn),"Numeric",NewGrp)
    L_TimestampChn = ChnCopy(L_TimestampChn,NewChn(0))

    For iLoop = 1 to ChnLength(L_AmplitudeChn)
        If (CHDx(iLoop,CNo(L_AmplitudeChn))<L_Threshold) Then
            CHDx(iLoop,CNo(L_AmplitudeChn)) = NULL
            CHDx(iLoop,CNo(L_TimestampChn)) = NULL
        End If
    Next

    CHD(iLoop-1,L_AmplitudeChn) = 0
    CHD(iLoop-1,L_TimestampChn) = 0

    Call Portal.Refresh
    Call oUDI.Sleep(100)
    Call ChnNovHandle(L_TimestampChn,L_AmplitudeChn,"Delete","XY",1,0,0)

    NewChn = array(L_TimestampChn,L_AmplitudeChn)
    ProcessNoise = NewChn

End Function

Function IdentifyChime(TimestampChn, AmplitudeChn, ChimesThreshold,NewGrp)

    Dim ChimesCounter, InitialWarningCounter, BeltminderACounter, BeltminderBCounter, UndefinedChimeCounter
    Dim iLoop, iLoop2, max, I
    Dim MyChannels(1), elements(), aux2(), ChnNumber
    Dim Timestamp, Amplitude, AmplitudeChnLength
    Dim InitialWarningThreshold, BeltminderAThreshold, BeltminderBThreshold

    TimestampChn = CNo(TimestampChn)
    AmplitudeChn = CNo(AmplitudeChn)

    InitialWarningCounter = 0
    BeltminderACounter = 0
    BeltminderBCounter = 0
    UndefinedChimeCounter = 0

    InitialWarningThreshold = ChimesThreshold(0)
    BeltminderAThreshold = ChimesThreshold(1)
    BeltminderBThreshold = ChimesThreshold(2)

    AmplitudeChnLength = ChnLength(AmplitudeChn)

    reDim chime(1,AmplitudeChnLength)
    reDim aux(AmplitudeChnLength,1)

    For iLoop = 1 to AmplitudeChnLength

        Call oUDI.Sleep(100)

        max = 0
        iLoop2=0

        If (iLoop<AmplitudeChnLength) Then
        Do 
            Timestamp = CHDx(iLoop,TimestampChn)
            Amplitude = CHDx(iLoop,AmplitudeChn)
            If (Amplitude <> 0) Then
        chime(0,iLoop2) = Timestamp
                chime(1,iLoop2) = Amplitude
                If (Amplitude>max) Then
                    max=Amplitude
                End If
            End If

            iLoop2=iLoop2+1
            iLoop=iLoop+1

        Loop While((iLoop<AmplitudeChnLength) AND ((CHDx(iLoop,TimestampChn)-chime(0,iLoop2-1))<2))

        End If

    If(max>BeltminderBThreshold) Then
        InitialWarningCounter=InitialWarningCounter+1
        MyChannels(0) = "Chime_Timestamp_InitialWarning_NA_" & InitialWarningCounter
        MyChannels(1) = "Chime_Amplitude_InitialWarning_NA_" & InitialWarningCounter
    ElseIf((max<BeltminderBThreshold) AND (max>BeltminderAThreshold)) Then
        BeltminderBCounter=BeltminderBCounter+1 
        MyChannels(0) = "Chime_Timestamp_Beltminder_B_" & BeltminderBCounter
        MyChannels(1) = "Chime_Amplitude_Beltminder_B_" & BeltminderBCounter
    ElseIf(max<BeltminderAThreshold) Then
        BeltminderACounter=BeltminderACounter+1 
        MyChannels(0) = "Chime_Timestamp_Beltminder_A_" & BeltminderACounter
        MyChannels(1) = "Chime_Amplitude_Beltminder_A_" & BeltminderACounter
    Else
        UndefinedChimeCounter=UndefinedChimeCounter+1
        MyChannels(0) = "Chime_Timestamp_UndefinedChimeThreshold_NA_" & UndefinedChimeCounter
        MyChannels(1) = "Chime_Amplitude_UndefinedChimeThreshold_NA_" & UndefinedChimeCounter
    End If

    reDim aux2(1,iLoop2-1)
    For I=0 to Ubound(aux2,2)
        aux2(0,I) = chime(0,I)
        aux2(1,I) = chime(1,I)
    Next
    Erase chime
    reDim chime(1,AmplitudeChnLength)

    ChnNumber = ArrayToChannels(aux2,MyChannels)
    Call ChnMove(ChnNumber(0), NewGrp)
    Call ChnMove(ChnNumber(1), NewGrp)
    ChnNumber(0) = "[" & NewGrp & "]/" & MyChannels(0)
    ChnNumber(1) = "[" & NewGrp & "]/" & MyChannels(1)


    Erase aux2

    ChimesCounter = InitialWarningCounter + BeltminderACounter + BeltminderBCounter + UndefinedChimeCounter

    aux(ChimesCounter-1,0) = ChnNumber(0)
    aux(ChimesCounter-1,1) = ChnNumber(1)

    Next

    reDim elements(ChimesCounter-1,1)

    For I=0 to Ubound(elements)
        elements(I,0) = aux(I,0)
        elements(I,1) = aux(I,1)
    Next

    IdentifyChime = elements 'Returns a channel list as a vector. The return are numbers.

    Erase aux
    Erase elements

End Function

Function IdentifyTelltale(TimestampChn, AmplitudeChn, TelltaleBeltminderAMinPeriodOn, TelltaleBeltminderABMaxPeriodOn,NewGrp)

    Dim TelltalesCounter, NotFlashingCounter, BeltminderACounter, BeltminderBCounter, UndefinedTelltaleCounter
    Dim iLoop, iLoop2, iLoop3, NoChangeLength, diff, I
   Dim Change, NoChange, LastValley, aux2, LastValley2
    Dim MyChannels(1), elements(), ChnNumber, TelltaleLength, Falling, Rising
    Dim Timestamp, Amplitude, AmplitudeChnLength, NoChangeLengthMax

    TimestampChn = CNo(TimestampChn)
    AmplitudeChn = CNo(AmplitudeChn)

    NotFlashingCounter = 0
    BeltminderACounter = 0
    BeltminderBCounter = 0
    UndefinedTelltaleCounter = 0
    NoChangeLengthMax = 0

    AmplitudeChnLength = ChnLength(AmplitudeChn)

    reDim Telltale(1,AmplitudeChnLength)
    reDim cycle(1,AmplitudeChnLength)
    reDim aux(AmplitudeChnLength,1)

    for iLoop3 = 1 to AmplitudeChnLength
   Telltale(0,iLoop3 - 1) = CHDx(iLoop3,TimestampChn)
    Telltale(1,iLoop3 - 1) = CHDx(iLoop3,AmplitudeChn)
    next
    TelltaleLength = Ubound(telltale,2)

    iLoop3 = 0
    Do While (Telltale(1,iLoop3)=0)
    iLoop3=iLoop3+1
    Loop
    iLoop3=iLoop3+1

    For iLoop = iLoop3 to TelltaleLength

        Call oUDI.Sleep(100)

        NoChangeLength = 0
        NoChangeLengthMax = 0 
        Change = 0
        iLoop2 = 0

        If (iLoop < AmplitudeChnLength) Then
            Do While((iLoop < AmplitudeChnLength) AND (Telltale(1,iLoop) = 0))
                iLoop = iLoop + 1
            Loop  
        End If

        If (iLoop < AmplitudeChnLength) Then
            Do  While((iLoop < AmplitudeChnLength) AND (NoChangeLength < (1+0.4)*TelltaleBeltminderABMaxPeriodOn))

                cycle(0,iLoop2) = Telltale(0,iLoop)
                cycle(1,iLoop2) = Telltale(1,iLoop)

               If (iLoop <> 0) Then
                    If (Telltale(1,iLoop - 1) <> Telltale(1,iLoop)) Then
                        Change = Telltale(0,iLoop)
                        LastValley = iLoop2
                        LastValley2 = iLoop
                            If (Telltale(1,iLoop) = 1) Then
                                Rising =  Telltale(0,iLoop)
                            Else
                                Falling =  Telltale(0,iLoop)
                                If (NoChangeLengthMax < (Falling - Rising)) Then
                                    NoChangeLengthMax = Falling - Rising
                                End If
                            End If
                    ElseIf ((Change <> 0) AND (Telltale(1,iLoop - 1) = Telltale(1,iLoop))) Then
                        NoChange = Telltale(0,iLoop)
                        NoChangeLength = NoChange - Change
                    End If
                End If

                iLoop = iLoop + 1
            iLoop2 = iLoop2 + 1     
            Loop 

            aux2 = cycle
            redim preserve aux2(1,LastValley-1)
            iLoop = LastValley2

            If(NoChangeLengthMax > (1+0.4)*TelltaleBeltminderABMaxPeriodOn) Then 'Above 40% of Beltminder A or B maximum period it is considered not flashing state 
                NotFlashingCounter = NotFlashingCounter + 1
                MyChannels(0) = "Telltale_Timestamp_NotFlashing_NA_" & NotFlashingCounter
                MyChannels(1) = "Telltale_Amplitude_NotFlashing_NA_" & NotFlashingCounter
            ElseIf((NoChangeLengthMax > (1-0.1)*TelltaleBeltminderAMinPeriodOn)) Then '10% of error is acceptable
                BeltminderACounter = BeltminderACounter + 1 
                MyChannels(0) = "Telltale_Timestamp_Beltminder_A_" & BeltminderACounter
                MyChannels(1) = "Telltale_Amplitude_Beltminder_A_" & BeltminderACounter
            ElseIf(NoChangeLengthMax < (1-0.1)*TelltaleBeltminderAMinPeriodOn) Then '10% of error is acceptable
                BeltminderBCounter = BeltminderBCounter + 1 
                MyChannels(0) = "Telltale_Timestamp_Beltminder_B_" & BeltminderBCounter
                MyChannels(1) = "Telltale_Amplitude_Beltminder_B_" & BeltminderBCounter
            Else
                UndefinedTelltaleCounter = UndefinedTelltaleCounter + 1
                MyChannels(0) = "Telltale_Timestamp_UndefinedTelltaleThreshold_NA_" & UndefinedTelltaleCounter
                MyChannels(1) = "Telltale_Amplitude_UndefinedTelltaleThreshold_NA_" & UndefinedTelltaleCounter
            End If

            aux2(1,0) = 0      
            aux2(1,Ubound(aux2)) = 0

            ChnNumber = ArrayToChannels(aux2,MyChannels,true)
            Call ChnMove(ChnNumber(0), NewGrp)
            Call ChnMove(ChnNumber(1), NewGrp)
            ChnNumber(0) = "[" & NewGrp & "]/" & MyChannels(0)
            ChnNumber(1) = "[" & NewGrp & "]/" & MyChannels(1)

            TelltalesCounter = NotFlashingCounter + BeltminderACounter + BeltminderBCounter + UndefinedTelltaleCounter

            aux(TelltalesCounter - 1,0) = ChnNumber(0)
            aux(TelltalesCounter - 1,1) = ChnNumber(1)

        End If
    Next

    reDim elements(TelltalesCounter - 1,1)

    For I = 0 to Ubound(elements)
        elements(I,0) = aux(I,0)
        elements(I,1) = aux(I,1)
    Next

    IdentifyTelltale = elements 'Returns a channel list as a vector. The return are numbers.

    Erase aux
    Erase elements

End Function

Function BeltminderFunction(Arg)

Dim ret, iLoop, iLoop2, BeltminderCounter
Dim Fs 'Sample rate (log sample rate = 100Hz)
Dim Threshold 'NoChangeLengthimum noise amplitude
Dim TimestampChn, TimestampChn2, ChimeAmplitudeChn, ProcessedTimestampChn, ProcessedChimeAmplitudeChn, GeneratedChns, NewGrp
Dim TelltaleAmplitudeChn
Dim chime1, telltale
Dim TelltaleBeltminderAMinPeriodOn, TelltaleBeltminderABMaxPeriodOn
Dim ChimesThreshold(3)

Fs = BeltminderFunctionArgs(0)
TimestampChn = BeltminderFunctionArgs(1)
ChimeAmplitudeChn = BeltminderFunctionArgs(2)


NewGrp = GroupIndexGet(GroupCreate("ProcessedChannels"))

TimestampChn = GenerateTimestampChn(TimestampChn,ChimeAmplitudeChn,Fs,NewGrp)
TimestampChn2 = TimestampChn

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'CHIME PROCESSING
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Threshold = BeltminderFunctionArgs(3) 
ret = ProcessNoise(ChimeAmplitudeChn,TimestampChn,Threshold,NewGrp)
ProcessedTimestampChn = ret(0)
ProcessedChimeAmplitudeChn = ret(1)

Call oUDI.Sleep(100)

ChimesThreshold(0) = BeltminderFunctionArgs(7) 'Initial warning chime threshold
ChimesThreshold(1) = BeltminderFunctionArgs(8) 'Beltminder A chime threshold
ChimesThreshold(2) = BeltminderFunctionArgs(9) 'Beltminder B chime threshold

GeneratedChns = IdentifyChime(ProcessedTimestampChn,ProcessedChimeAmplitudeChn, ChimesThreshold,NewGrp)

ReDim chime1 (Ubound(GeneratedChns,1))
For iLoop = 0 to Ubound(chime1)
    Set chime1(iLoop) = New ChimeCycle

    chime1(iLoop).Index = iLoop
    chime1(iLoop).TimestampCh = GeneratedChns(iLoop,0)
    chime1(iLoop).AmplitudeCh = GeneratedChns(iLoop,1)
Next
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'TELLTALE PROCESSING
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
TelltaleAmplitudeChn = BeltminderFunctionArgs(4)
TelltaleBeltminderAMinPeriodOn = BeltminderFunctionArgs(5)
TelltaleBeltminderABMaxPeriodOn = BeltminderFunctionArgs(6)

GeneratedChns = IdentifyTelltale(TimestampChn,TelltaleAmplitudeChn, TelltaleBeltminderAMinPeriodOn, TelltaleBeltminderABMaxPeriodOn,NewGrp)

ReDim telltale1 (Ubound(GeneratedChns,1))
For iLoop = 0 to Ubound(telltale1)
    Set telltale1(iLoop) = New TelltaleCycle

    telltale1(iLoop).Index = iLoop
    telltale1(iLoop).TimestampCh = GeneratedChns(iLoop,0)
    telltale1(iLoop).AmplitudeCh = GeneratedChns(iLoop,1)
Next
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'BELTMINDER WARNING FUNCTION PROCESSING
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim telltale1_Temp, chime1_Temp, NoFlashingNoChimeOrder
telltale1_Temp = telltale1
chime1_Temp = chime1

BeltminderCounter = 0
NoFlashingNoChimeOrder = 1
For iLoop = 0 to Ubound(telltale1_Temp)
    For iLoop2 = 0 to Ubound(chime1_Temp)

        If((chime1_Temp(iLoop2).FunctionType <> "InitialWarning_NA") AND (telltale1_Temp(iLoop).FunctionType = "NotFlashing_NA")) Then
            ReDim Preserve beltminder1(BeltminderCounter)
            Set beltminder1(BeltminderCounter) = New BeltminderCycle
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).Index = BeltminderCounter
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).FunctionType = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).FunctionType
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).OrderOfThisType = NoFlashingNoChimeOrder
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).StartTime = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).StartTime
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).EndTime = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).EndTime
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).ChimeObjIndex = "N/A"
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).TelltaleObjIndex = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).Index
            BeltminderCounter = BeltminderCounter + 1
            NoFlashingNoChimeOrder = NoFlashingNoChimeOrder + 1
            chime1_Temp(iLoop2).Reinitialize
            telltale1_Temp(iLoop).Reinitialize

        End If

        If((chime1_Temp(iLoop2).FunctionType = "InitialWarning_NA") AND (telltale1_Temp(iLoop).FunctionType = "NotFlashing_NA")) Then
            ReDim Preserve beltminder1(BeltminderCounter)
            Set beltminder1(BeltminderCounter) = New BeltminderCycle
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).Index = BeltminderCounter
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).FunctionType = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).FunctionType
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).OrderOfThisType = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).OrderOfThisType
            If(telltale1_Temp(iLoop).StartTime < chime1_Temp(iLoop2).StartTime) Then
                beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).StartTime = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).StartTime  
            Else beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).StartTime = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).StartTime
            End If  
            If(telltale1_Temp(iLoop).EndTime > chime1_Temp(iLoop2).EndTime) Then
                beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).EndTime = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).EndTime
            Else beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).EndTime = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).EndTime
            End If
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).ChimeObjIndex = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).Index
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).TelltaleObjIndex = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).Index
            BeltminderCounter = BeltminderCounter + 1
            chime1_Temp(iLoop2).Reinitialize
            telltale1_Temp(iLoop).Reinitialize
        End If

        If((telltale1_Temp(iLoop).FunctionType <> "") AND (telltale1_Temp(iLoop).FunctionType = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).FunctionType) AND (telltale1_Temp(iLoop).OrderOfThisType = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).OrderOfThisType)) Then
            ReDim Preserve beltminder1(BeltminderCounter)
            Set beltminder1(BeltminderCounter) = New BeltminderCycle
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).Index = BeltminderCounter
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).FunctionType = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).FunctionType
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).OrderOfThisType = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).OrderOfThisType
            If(telltale1_Temp(iLoop).StartTime < chime1_Temp(iLoop2).StartTime) Then
                beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).StartTime = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).StartTime  
            Else beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).StartTime = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).StartTime
            End If  
            If(telltale1_Temp(iLoop).EndTime > chime1_Temp(iLoop2).EndTime) Then
                beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).EndTime = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).EndTime
            Else beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).EndTime = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).EndTime
            End If
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).ChimeObjIndex = chime1_Temp(iLoop2).Index
            beltminder1(BeltminderCounter).TelltaleObjIndex = telltale1_Temp(iLoop).Index
            BeltminderCounter = BeltminderCounter + 1
            chime1_Temp(iLoop2).Reinitialize
            telltale1_Temp(iLoop).Reinitialize
        End IF
    Next
Next

Erase telltale1_Temp
Erase chime1_Temp

'For iLoop2 = 0 to Ubound(beltminder1)
'   Call LogFileWrite( "Index: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).Index & vbCrLf &"FunctionType: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).FunctionType & vbCrLf & "OrderOfThisType: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).OrderOfThisType  & vbCrLf & "StartTime: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).StartTime  & vbCrLf & "EndTime: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).EndTime  & vbCrLf & "Duration: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).Duration  & vbCrLf & "ChimeObjIndex: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).ChimeObjIndex  & vbCrLf & "TelltaleObjIndex: " & beltminder1(iLoop2).TelltaleObjIndex)
'Next

BeltminderFunction = Array (chime1, telltale1, beltminder1,TimestampChn2)

End Function
```

Comment: Wow, where to begin...I'm not sure what you expect us to do with this? Ideally [so] questions should include a [mcve] which this is not. I can tell you one thing, I've never seen properties used the way you are using them here and not even sure how some values are being referenced, you're almost trying to use a `Property` as a `Function` / `Sub` which they are not.

Comment: VBScript... It's been a while :)

Comment: 600 LoC? Like, *seriously*? Please reduce that wall of code to a digestible sample that still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Somehow this feels relevant - [Your Code: OOP or POO?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/your-code-oop-or-poo/)

Comment: Decent [Using Classes within VBScript](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092399-1.shtml) *(split into four parts)* you may find useful.

Comment: An excellent explanation of [OOP principles applied to VBScript by @Ekkehard-Horner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860947/692942) well worth a read!