# How to use Objects within Dictionaries in VBScript?

Tags: dictionary, object, vbscript

I have created a simple class, GaugeChart:

```
Class GaugeChart 
    Public Essential
    Public Lifestyle
    Public Spending
    Public Average
End Class
```

That I wish to use inside a dictionary:

```
   Dim items, objGaugeDic, objGaugeChart, objGaugeChartread
    Set objGaugeDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set objGaugeChart = New GaugeChart  ' from GaugeChartClass.asp
    objGaugeChart.Essential = intChart1Essential
    objGaugeChart.Lifestyle = intChart1Lifestyle
    objGaugeChart.Spending = intChart1Spending
    objGaugeChart.Average = Chart1Avg
    Set objGaugeDic ("Goal1") = objGaugeChart 
    Response.Write("Essential: " + Cstr(objGaugeChart.Essential) + "<br />")


    Set objGaugeChart = New GaugeChart  ' from GaugeChartClass.asp
    objGaugeChart.Essential = intChart2Essential
    objGaugeChart.Lifestyle = intChart2Lifestyle
    objGaugeChart.Spending = intChart2Spending
    objGaugeChart.Average = Chart2Avg
    Set objGaugeDic ("Goal2") = objGaugeChart 


    ' load values
    'objGuageDic.Add "Goal1", objGaugeElements
    Response.Write("objGaugeDic Keys: " + Cstr(objGaugeDic.Count))

    For i = 0 To objGaugeDic.Count -1 'Iterate the array
        Response.Write( CType(objGaugeDic.Item(i),objGaugeChart).Essential + "<br />")

    Next
```

Dictionary keys = 2 - so that's fine.  However when I try to access the object and properties within the dictionary using CType, I get a runtime error.

Trying with `objGaugeDic.Item(i).Essential` I get undefined.

I have also tried, instead of `Set objGaugeDic ("Goal1") = objGaugeChart, to do`objGaugeDic.Add "Goal1", objGaugeChart` .

How can I access the object properties of each dictionary item of type `objGaugeDic`, something like `Response.Write( CType(objGaugeDic.Item(i),objGaugeChart).Essential + "<br />")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionary of Objects/Classes in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543942/dictionary-of-objects-classes-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the objects in the dictionary by keys within `For Each` loop:

```vb
For Each strKey In objGaugeDic
    Response.Write(objGaugeDic(strKey).Essential + "<br />")
Next
```

Also, you may get an array of keys outside of the loop, and refer to the objects in the dictionary via keys by index:

```vb
arrKeys = objGaugeDic.Keys()
For i = 0 To objGaugeDic.Count -1
    Response.Write(objGaugeDic(arrKeys(i)).Essential + "<br />")
Next
```